# Apache .htaccess close connection immediately with no response

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Hello in nginx it is as easy as

return 444;

In apache I am trying to add this basic functionality but I can not.

RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=444]

Does not seem to work.

How do I solve this?

A very simple request, yet no documentation on this after countless google searches.

Comment: 444 is not a valid response code.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r):

> Any valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax
>   [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is
>   specified. The status code specified need not necessarily be a
>   redirect (3xx) status code. However, if a status code is outside the
>   redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped
>   entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the L were used.

Also, according to [this](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45478#c1):

> AFAICT, Only 2.2 doc says you can supply a non-3xx status code. 2.2.x
>   does what the manual says, returns the status and stops rewriting (and
>   no redirect of course.

For error you can see your error.logs, there will be something like this:

> RewriteRule: invalid HTTP response code '444' for flag 'R'

For alternative of **Nginx 444** you can look [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/726029/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-return-444) (comment about mod_security).

Also, maybe [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/misc/security_tips.html) will be helpful.